# How do i solve a problem that says Repository not found?

Tags: github, repository

I created a repo on github and in the local directory command prompt on windows i typed git clone https URL string of the repo and it has been telling me remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository.

Please how do i go about solving this problem?

Thanks.

I have deleted the repo on github. I tried to recreate it, ensuring its the same letter case with the folder in the local system.

C:\Users\Olaniyi Adeosun\Desktop\cashurban>git clone https://github.com/titelecoms/cashurban.git
Cloning into 'cashurban'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/titelecoms/cashurban.git/' not found

Answer (score 1):

If it's a private repository, then git has to be logged on the right github account to have access. You can configure with

```
git config --global user.name "<username>"
git config --global user.email <your@email.ca>
```

or remove last argument to read your current configuration.

If it does not work, it might also be a https connection error, then you can give a try to git://

```
git clone git://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>.git
```